# Make bacon less salty

Tags: salt, bacon, hamburgers

I just finished a burger that I got at a local butcher/deli.  The burger was half ground chuck and half apple wood smoked bacon.  It was delicious.  The only problem I have with it is that it was very salty.  I do not know if the butcher added any additional salt, but assuming he did not, how would go about making my own version of a half ground chuck/half ground bacon burger less salty?  This is assuming all of the salt is coming from the bacon.

There was also a slice of American cheese, lettuce, tomato and mayo on it.

Answer (score 2):

Not all bacon is equally salty. Look at nutrition labels on the bacon when you go shopping, find the least salty bacon you can, and try that. You'll be best off if you cook a small amount of your meat mixture to taste, so that if you manage to end up with too little salt, you can add some back in. If it's still too salty, then all you can really do is add other, less salty meat. I imagine a burger made from 1/4 bacon would still have tons of bacon flavor.

Comment: Agreed. My first thought was to substitute half the bacon with ground unsalted pork.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that is what ill try.  Maybe even smoke my own bacon and cut down on the salt. :)

I didn't know if there was another ingredient I could add to the burger that would cut the flavor of the salt.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a sip of milk to the mixture and leave it for ~20 min. Then get rid of the excess moisture, and you're up to go.
Good luck with those burgers.

Answer (score 0):

Soak the bacon in cold water in the fridge for 8-12 hours, then dry.  Once the bacon is as dry as it would normally be grind it with an equal portion of beef.